# Localhost port is missing on some links after downgrading MAMP

Tags: urls, localhost

I downgraded to MAMP after trying MAMP pro, everything is fine except some of the links don’t have localhost port; eg…localhost/about, when it should be localhost:8888/about. Some of the links include the port, and some don’t, but I’m not sure why? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a Wordpress specific question. You'd probably have better luck on StackOverflow.

Comment: I tried StackOverflow and was told it wasn't a code specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some of your link are using `localhost` while others are using `localhost:8888`, you'll want to make sure that all of the links in your database are set to `localhost:8888`. Follow these steps:

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder in your **localhost** where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://localhost:8888/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. Enter your `/localhost/` URL in the **`search for…`** field and the new URL (`/localhost:8888/`) in the **`replace with…`** field

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and showing me this awesome tool! After the search It appears the paths in question are correct in the db. eg... localhost:8888/about was one of the search results for just 'localhost', it would of been replaced with localhost:8888:8888. I followed your in directions in step 4, is there any other reason only a couple links would exclude the port. Also, if I link to one of the urls that aren't working from wp-admin in 'pages' the link works.

Comment: Also, the search and replace tool says my port is 3306 when it has always been 8888, is that normal, or is there something off with that? Everything else is correct.

Comment: @AnthonyD In that case, use `/localhost/` instead of just `localhost` to prevent doubling up on the replacements. Make sure you set the replacement URL as `localhost:8888/` as well witht the `/`. I can't speak for whatever your default port it, you'd have to look into that. Updated my answer

Comment: I tried /localhost/ and only 1 item was found in _options, but when I looked at the results I couldn't find anything. After looking more closely I found that only two links have this problem. Is the db the only thing that would cause this?

Comment: @AnthonyD Yes, since your content is stored there. It also sounds like those are the two links your were mentioning in your question. Try replacing them and see if that fixes it.

Comment: When you say replace them do you mean in the Wordpress dashboard? I tried deleting them and recreating them but that didn't work. I also tried specifying the url to include http://localhost:8888, instead of just /about (even though this works with the others), but it made no difference.

Comment: @AnthonyD Just checking in on your progress, if your scenario is different, may you post an update in your question so I can get a better idea on where you are?

Comment: Hey Ethan, I ended up Just slightly changing the page names / URLS, and template names for the two pages that were broken. It was a matter of about vs about-us, and was much easer to just rename them. I'm not sure if thats what you were suggesting in your last response. I would of liked to have figured out what was causing this in the db but it seemed like nothing I tried revealed any clues. Thanks, for showing me the replace tool and and giving me an idea of what to do in the future if something like this happens again.

Comment: @AnthonyD Glad that you were able to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If MAMP Pro was set to use port 8888 then you should set up MAMP to be the same. When you see `http://localhost` with no port specified, that means it's looking to the default port, which is port 80.

You can set this in MAMP 'Preferences'. The reference to port 3306 is related to the port for MySQL. If you click the 'Set MAMP ports to default' button it will set the ports too 8888 for webservers and 8889 for MySQL.

[image: MAMP preferences screen]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. MAMP ports are already set to default, its really weird because only two links are doing this.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing permalinks? Just go to 'settings/permalinks' and click 'Save'.

Comment: Thanks, Jermey. I did, but problem still persists. when I enter the correct url manually it works fine for those two links. Does this mean the problem has to be db related. I tried the search and replace as suggested by @Ethan, but according to the results the links were correct.